# Plot the grouped fields in the groupby pandas Function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to group by and apply a pandas df with the next rows

```
['CpuEff',
 'my_remote_host',
 'GLIDEIN_CMSSite',
 'BytesRecvd',
 'BytesSent',
 'CMSPrimaryPrimaryDataset',
 'CMSPrimaryDataTier',
 'DESIRED_CMSDataset',
 'DESIRED_CMSPileups',
 'type_prefix',
 'CMS_Jobtype',
 'CMS_Type',
 'CommittedTime',
 'CommittedSlotTime',
 'CpusProvisioned',
 'CpuTimeHr',
 'JobRunCount',
 'LastRemoteHost']
```

Then, I apply the group by and calculate the mean of each field and passing into a new df

```
grouped = df.groupby(['DESIRED_CMSDataset'])
df_mean=grouped.mean()
df_mean
```

And check the new df fields,

```
list(df_mean.columns)
```

```
['CpuEff',
 'BytesRecvd',
 'BytesSent',
 'CommittedTime',
 'CommittedSlotTime',
 'CpusProvisioned',
 'CpuTimeHr',
 'JobRunCount']
```

The issue is, I want to plot a histogram showing 'DESIRED_CMSDataset' and the respective mean values of each row, but it does not allow me as long as in new dataframe this row disappear.

Is there any way to perform the same operation without losing the gropued row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think (i am on mobile rn) if you aggregate this way your group column becomes the index of the new df. Try running `df = df.reset_index()`. I think adding `as_index=False` during groupby also works. Will confirm and edit answer tomorrow. You could also plot `df.index` if you want to keep it that way